# Getting the date from a comparison of values within two columns through time

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to spot dates (so rows) where the number of likes is smaller than retweets.
My data looks like

```
Date               Text    Like     Retweet
28/02/2020         wow!!!   1          0
28/02/2020         I have a baby!!!   1          4
28/02/2020         No words  0          0
...
05/12/2019         I love cooking! 4    2
05/12/2020         Hello world!    1    1 
...
```

To find the numbers of likes/retweets per date I did as follows:

```
df.groupby([df.Date])["Like"].sum()
df.groupby([df.Date])["Retweet"].sum()
```

Now I would like to see when the number of likes is greater than that one of retweet (in the example should be 5/12/2020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Date')[['Like','Retweet']].sum()
grouped[grouped['Like'] > grouped['Retweet']].index

# similarly
# grouped.query('Like > Retweet').index
```

Comment: Thank you Quang Hoang. As soon as possible, I will mark your answer! :)